# Compare to check if application version is the latest powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm just learning Powershell and I'm pretty new to it.

How do I fetch the version number of an application to check if its the latest.

For example: I would like to check if the Adobe application installed is an accepted version.

I created an array with a collection of all acceptable version numbers.

Now what I want to do is check if the installed adobe version matches one of the array values.

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: there is a `.Version` property for  many fileinfo objects. you can get that with `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem`. then you can compare a string version number to that by using the `[version]` type accelerator to convert the string to a real version number. at that point the two items with both be version objects.

Comment: PLEASE, read the `Tour` page for this site. you are in violation of the rules ... and that `Tour` will show you how to fix that. [*grin*]

Comment: I'm new to this site. How do I visit the tour page?

Comment: a net search for `stackoverflow tour` leads to the following page [*grin*] ... Tour - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Which rule is this post in violation of?

Comment: @Scratte - the rule about posting `code to help with`. [*grin*] there is no code, nor any indication how things failed to work as expected.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey If someone asks **how** to do something, why do you need code? They're asking how to get the installed version number. They're not saying they have an idea that they've tried and failed at.  Also see [Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code/286760#286760). What's with the "[grin]"?

Comment: @Jaffer The Tour page and all the Help Center pages are available when you click on the little round question mark icon at the upper right corner. To be better prepared and to know what is expected, I'd advice you to spend a weekend on reading them. At least all the pages about "Asking", if you're going to ask Questions a lot. It's generally expected anyone active on the site know the content/information given in the Help Center.

Comment: @Scratte - my reading of that indicates this Question better fits over on SuperUser. adding some indication that the OP tried SOMETHING helps one know how to point the OP at a better Answer.

Comment: @Scratte - the `[*grin*] ` is my way to convey some of the sideband info that plain text lacks. my eyesight is bad enuf that the usual emoticons are hard to see, so i spell them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Product | select Name,Version,Caption,Description,Vendor,InstallDate,InstallSource,Language,PackageName
```

If you're only interested in specific applications/vendors use `-Filter` parameter, as this cmdlet takes a lot of time to execute as it is.